# Can i generage invite link from chat id telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I need to generate invite link to group in telegram to bind button that have link to group. I can do this with invite link but idk how to generate it. How to generate it or there are other ways to bind button with telethon?

I searched for any libraries or sites to generate link but didn't find any.

Comment: "*I searched for any libraries or sites to generate link but didn't find any*" could you please [edit] your question and indicate what you've searched for exactly? As in: what terms did you use in the web search? It can help answerers better understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are admin of that chat

using pyrogram library

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/create_chat_invite_link#pyrogram.Client.create_chat_invite_link

Comment: Note that the question was tagged as `telethon` though, so this may not be a valid solution for OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).